# codenameone simulator file access error

Tags: database, java-me, lwuit, codenameone

I develope an application with codenameone and now I add Perst database engine to it.

When I want to open database file I get error "File access error". Here is error output:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at com.codename1.impl.javase.Executor$1.run(Executor.java:87)
at com.codename1.ui.Display.processSerialCalls(Display.java:984)
at com.codename1.ui.Display.mainEDTLoop(Display.java:827)
at com.codename1.ui.RunnableWrapper.run(RunnableWrapper.java:119)
at com.codename1.impl.CodenameOneThread.run(CodenameOneThread.java:176)
```

Caused by: org.garret.perst.StorageError: File access error: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.garret.perst.impl.RmsFile.open(RmsFile.java:169)
    at org.garret.perst.impl.StorageImpl.open(StorageImpl.java:827)
    at com.saminray.database.DBManager.foo(DBManager.java:24)
    at com.saminray.mobilebank.MainUI.(MainUI.java:21)
    at com.saminray.mobilebank.Main.start(Main.java:78)
    ... 9 more
Java Result: 1

I think it depend on codenameone simulator. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot add an external database to codenameone apps.
CodenameOne supports sqlite if exists on devices (IOS, Android, RIM) for J2ME you have the Storage API which is more portable and work on all platforms.